# googleApiClient won't connect

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api-client

Trying to get the latitude and longitude of my current location. I figured it's because the googleApiClient won't connect. As a result, my onConnected method is not called which is where I get the latitude and longitude values. I've tried all the suggestions on here but it still doesn't work.

Note: I also get no errors at all when I run the app.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.location2;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private TextView longitudeText;
    private TextView latitudeText;

    protected Location lastLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        longitudeText = findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
        latitudeText =  findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);


        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        //googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

        this.googleApiClient.connect();
        // Here i check if the googleApiClient is connected by printing  
        if (this.googleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermission();
        } else {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Logic to handle location object
                                latitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                                longitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }



    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new
                String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Connection suspendedd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the GoogleApiClient connection is the problem? Does any of your `Toast` show up?

There is a [tutorial](http://androidtechpoint.blogspot.com/2017/01/android-tutorial-to-get-last-known.html) on getting the last known location using Google Fused API. In case it's a manifest problem, the tutorial also has a manifest included. It's not completely the same as what you want, but I thought it may help figure out what implementation went wrong.